# Host error during request eTicketCouponLLSRQ

Tags: sabre

Sometimes I receive ERR.SWS.HOST.CONNECTOR_ERROR while invoking eTicketCouponLLSRQ and sometimes I receive valid response. What is wrong?
Thank you!

I'm working in CERT, SRW version is 2.15.2 (SDK version), PCC Z4KB, EPR 1112

RQ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><eTicketCouponRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" TimeStamp="2018-04-23T10:36:18.907" Version="2.0.0">
    <Ticketing eTicketNumber="5552484960880"/>
</eTicketCouponRQ>
```

RS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><eTicketCouponRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" TimeStamp="2018-04-23T10:36:18.907" Version="2.0.0">
    <Ticketing eTicketNumber="XXXXXXXXX0880"/>
</eTicketCouponRQ><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><eTicketCouponRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.0">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="Unknown">
  <stl:Error timeStamp="2018-04-23T01:33:59-05:00" type="Application">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message>Sending request to the Host failed</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.CONNECTOR_ERROR</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</eTicketCouponRS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a timeout on a Sabre backend, meaning that it was not able to process it.

If you get many of this, I recommend you to contact the Sabre API helpdesk